# Trapping key presses but filtering for certain situations

Tags: jquery

Currently I am using this code snippet that I found on another stackoverflow question.

```
$(document).bind("keypress", function (ev) {
    if (ev.keyCode == 13 && ev.target.type != "textarea")
        ev.preventDefault();
});
```

This works great for most cases, but I'd like to be able to add another condition where pressing enter on a certain textbox will trigger the default button to click. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code for binding the right textarea, this behavior

```
$('#textareaID').bind("keypress", function (ev) {
        if (ev.keyCode == 13 )
         {
                $("#yourbuttonId").trigger("click");
        }
      });
```